# how to parse json having multiple values

Tags: android, json

I am trying to parse a json

```
{"objects":[{"obimages":["obj_icon\/133431837745.jpg","obj_icon\/1334318377319.jpg","obj_icon\/1334318378384.jpg","obj_icon\/1334318378ajmer21.jpg","obj_icon\/1334318378df.jpg"]}
}
```

i have to get the values in "obimages" individually.
can any one please help me.

Comment: i think its jsonarray of images...

Comment: i am able to parse content in obimages as a single string,but i want it seperately.

Comment: i have to get each image link so that i can download it

Comment: Your JSON sample isn't valid. You're missing a closing `]` right before the last `}`, assuming that there isn't more missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this site, this will explain how to parse a jason link, http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Use the classes JSONObject and JSONArray to parse JSON

Comment: yes i did it, but i am getting the complete links in a single string, is there any way to get it individually.

Comment: It is a JSON array, so you should be able to get the items individually, post your code.