# How I may parse JSON in java

Tags: java, android

I'm stuck with parsing JSON in Java using org.json. My JSON looks like this

```
[{"id" : "1",
  "type" : "City",
  "description" : [ "short_description" : "some data",
                    "long_description" : "some data",
                    "postal_code" : "49045",
                    "population" : "900000",
                  ],
     }
 ],
```

How I may parse for example an element of tag description, for example long_description ?

Comment: take a look at this article: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html

Comment: Refer this previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699348/how-to-parse-json-having-multiple-values/10699469#10699469

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [json-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) the you can simply add it as a library to your existing project and do like this:

data (JSON):

> {'foo':'bar',  'coolness':2.0,  'altitude':39000, 'pilot':{'firstName':'Buzz','lastName':'Aldrin'},  'mission':'apollo 11'}

code to parse the data:

```
import java.io.InputStream;

import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
import net.sf.json.JSONSerializer;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class JsonParsing {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InputStream is = 
                JsonParsing.class.getResourceAsStream( "sample-json.txt");
        String jsonTxt = IOUtils.toString( is );

        JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON( jsonTxt );        
        double coolness = json.getDouble( "coolness" );
        int altitude = json.getInt( "altitude" );
        JSONObject pilot = json.getJSONObject("pilot");
        String firstName = pilot.getString("firstName");
        String lastName = pilot.getString("lastName");

        System.out.println( "Coolness: " + coolness );
        System.out.println( "Altitude: " + altitude );
        System.out.println( "Pilot: " + lastName );
    }
}
```

**References:**

- http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/257-how-to-parse-json-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray values = new JSONArray(yourstring);
for(int i = 0 ; i < values.length(); i++){
    JSONObject object= values.get(i);
    JSONArray desc = object.getJSONArray("description");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without the library -

```
try  {
    JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(yourString);
    JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) tokener.nextValue();
    String output = jsonObj.getString("streamUrl");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.v("Logtag", "Problem in decoding json");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //import java.util.ArrayList;
 //import org.bson.Document;


 Document root = Document.parse("{ \"foo\" : \"bar\", \"coolness\" : 2.0, \"altitude\" : 39000, \"pilot\" : { \"firstName\" : \"Buzz\", \"lastName\" : \"Aldrin\" }, \"mission\" : \"apollo 11\" }");

 System.out.println(((String)root.get("foo")));
 System.out.println((root.get("coolness")));
 System.out.println((root.get("altitude")));
 System.out.println(((String)((Document)root.get("pilot")).get("firstName")));
 System.out.println(((String)((Document)root.get("pilot")).get("lastName")));
 System.out.println(((String)root.get("mission")));
```